# c# openfiledilaog, Open file when program starts

Tags: c#

I have a question about the openfiledialog command. What i an trying to do is open a file when the programm starts, I have the directory in a .ini file and when.

The opening of the ini file is already fixed and i can already use the directory name in a textbox.

So a quick recap of what im trying to do, I am trying to make the openfiledialog open a file with the initial directory from the .ini file.

Does someone have solution?
Im pasting the code ASAP

Comment: So what is your problem? Just take the path of the initial directory from your ini file and set it as file before you open the OpenFileDialog.

Comment: Do you mean it like this: 'Openfiledialog1.openfile(initialdirectory)';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting the [`InitialDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory.aspx) to the desired path:

```
myOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = variableHoldingThePathFromIni;
```

That is, if I managed to get what you want from the question - it's a bit hard to tell.

Comment: And then i put it in somekind of textbox right because i did this:

Comment: private void typelistbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Controller controller = GetCurrentController();
            if (controller == null)
            {
                // TODO velden leegmaken
            }
            else
            {

                appfile.InitialDirectory = (controller.Lastfile);

                textBox1.Text = appfile.FileName;
                textBox2.Text = controller.Useboot;
                _comPortComboBox.SelectedItem = controller.Port;

            }


        }